# Problema leyendo cadena de bytes

Tags: java, stream, io

Antes que nada, soy nuevo en esto, espero que no haya hecho muy larga la duda y pueda ser lo suficientemente claro en la pregunta.

Estoy intentando leer una cadena de bytes enviada desde un modulo arduino via BT con el caracter 'H' o un string, lo que sea que envíe desde arduino me llega en caracteres desconocidos � la misma cantidad de bytes que envío, pero todos como caracteres desconocido. Estimo que estoy teniendo problemas en la decodificacion en ambas partes pero no se como realmente.

+Ya probé seteando charset en ASCII desde android studio tanto para el .write como para el .read. La conexión funciona perfecto. Por favor, si alguien puede decirme que esta pasando. desde ya muchas gracias.

Parte OutputStream:

```
   btnEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                byte[] bytes = et1.getText().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
                mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);
                et1.setText("");
            }
        });

 //////////////


 public void write(byte[] bytes) {

            String text = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

            Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputstream: " + text);
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
                Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputstream: " + bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error writing to output stream. " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }
```

Parte OutputStream:

```js
 public void run (){
            byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytes;

            while(true){
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    String incomingMessage = new String (buffer,0,bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG,"InputStream: " + incomingMessage);

                    Intent incomingMessageIntent = new Intent("incommingMessage");
                    incomingMessageIntent.putExtra("El mensaje", incomingMessage);

                    Log.d(TAG,"Mensaje enviado a la main actv " + incomingMessage);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast (incomingMessageIntent);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Error leyendo Imputstream"  +e.getMessage());

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Print en celular:

```js
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String text = intent.getStringExtra("El mensaje");
            
            mensaje.append(text + "\n");
            tvin.setText(mensaje);
```

Logcat:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Solucioné el problema!, sin darme cuenta mi módulo BT estaba seteado en 38400 baudios o algo parecido y yo lo estaba inicializando en 9600, lo setié en 9600 y comenzo a mandar caracteres! Lo informo por si a alguien le llega a pasar lo mismo, ya saben!